# Main window vertical scrollbar is sometimes missing

Tags: bug, design, scrolling

The main window scrollbar is unpredicatably missing on many StackExchange sites.

[image]

Here is a screenshot of a set of search results with no scrollbar.

The scrollbar can be recovered by reloading the page, or (for example) opening the "Recent inbox messages" dropdown. Sometimes the scrollbar is shown, other times it is not, on the same page. I've noticed this for about a week.

It seems while loading the page, the scroll bar is drawn, but then removed once the page has fully loaded.  This is chrome Version 94.0.4606.81 (Official Build) (64-bit) On Gnome 3.38.5 (Unbuntu 21.04)

[image]

For comparison here is the same page after a reload with the scrollbar visible on the right.

Comment: Can you provide steps to reproduce, or does it seem random?

Comment: It seems random, it can occur on multiple sites across the network,and on various pages such as "Home" and "Questions" and (as above) "Search results". A reload will usually fix the problem, but it happens often enough to be frustrating.

Comment: When that happens, can you still scroll down or is the page not fully rendered?

Comment: The page is fully rendered. And you can scroll down with cursor keys.

Comment: Most likely something local, on your side, cause this. Try to disable all userscripts, including ad blockers, as they change the page contents in unknown ways thus many times cause exactly such notorious bugs. Also more than once I heard about external  security software (e.g. anti virus) which hooks into browsers and doing the same: mess with the contents to "protect" against possible threats, so try to (temporarily!) disable those too. Hopefully this way you'll find what's causing it and can share with others here.

Comment: Also, BTW - there is picture of you in the screenshots (probably?) You might consider posting new screenshots, without it?

Comment: It does seem to have been a browser extension, as turning them all off and I can't reproduce this.  So I'll try to divide and conquer to find which one.

Comment: I got this myself and tried to investigate it with the browser console, but inspecting made a scrollbar appear, even after I dismissed the inspection window.